# NativeScript: GridLayout alignment issue

Tags: xml, nativescript, grid-layout, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am very new to `NativeScript`. I am following its own document. I am trying for UI Alignment. I unable to achieve this. I am using `Xcode IDE` and running in `iOS Simulator`.

Groceries Logo should be in Top

Textfields should be in middle

Sign up button should be in Bottom

**Attempt 1**

```
<Page loaded="loaded">

<GridLayout height=auto horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" columns="*" rows="auto,auto,*"  backgroundColor="brown">
    <Image src="res://logo" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top" col="0" row="0"></Image>
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto,auto,auto" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="lightgray" col="0" row="1">

        <TextField class="userTxtFld" id="email" text="{{ email }}" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"  col="0" row="0"/>
        <TextField secure="true" text="{{ password }}" hint="Password" col="0" row="1"/>
        <Button text="Sign in" tap="signIn"  col="0" row="2"/>

    </GridLayout>
    <Button text="Sign up for Groceries" class="link" tap="register" verticalAlignment="bottom" col="0" row="2"/>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
<Page loaded="loaded">

<GridLayout height="auto" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" columns="*" rows="auto,auto,*"  backgroundColor="brown">
    <Image src="res://logo" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top" col="0" row="0"></Image>
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto,auto,auto" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="lightgray" col="0" row="1">

        <TextField class="userTxtFld" id="email" text="{{ email }}" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"  col="0" row="0"/>
        <TextField secure="true" text="{{ password }}" hint="Password" col="0" row="1"/>
        <Button text="Sign in" tap="signIn"  col="0" row="2"/>

    </GridLayout>
    <Button text="Sign up for Groceries" class="link" tap="register" verticalAlignment="bottom" col="0" row="2"/>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

**Issue**

In attempt 1, **height=auto** and in attempt 2, **height="auto"**

I need output as Attempt 1.

I dont know, why `backgroundcolor` is not displaying in **height=auto**

I dont know, why `UI Alignment` is not fixing in **height="auto"**

If **height="auto"** is right way, how to do get output as Attempt 1?

Kindly help me this.

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want first row to be top,second to be middle and last one to be at bottom then you should use `rows="auto,*,auto"` which will do that exactly.

try this

```
<Page loaded="loaded">

<GridLayout height="100%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" columns="*" rows="auto,*,auto"  backgroundColor="brown">
    <Image src="res://logo" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top" col="0" row="0"></Image>
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto,auto,auto" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="lightgray" col="0" row="1">

        <TextField class="userTxtFld" id="email" text="{{ email }}" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"  col="0" row="0"/>
        <TextField secure="true" text="{{ password }}" hint="Password" col="0" row="1"/>
        <Button text="Sign in" tap="signIn"  col="0" row="2"/>

    </GridLayout>
    <Button text="Sign up for Groceries" class="link" tap="register" verticalAlignment="bottom" col="0" row="2"/>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

same output can also be achieve by using assigning same row number to all 3 rows and using `rows="*"`.

like this.

```
<Page loaded="loaded">

<GridLayout height="100%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" columns="*" rows="*"  backgroundColor="brown">
    <Image src="res://logo" stretch="aspectFit" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="top" col="0" row="0"></Image>
    <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto,auto,auto" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="lightgray" col="0" row="0">

        <TextField class="userTxtFld" id="email" text="{{ email }}" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"  col="0" row="0"/>
        <TextField secure="true" text="{{ password }}" hint="Password" col="0" row="1"/>
        <Button text="Sign in" tap="signIn"  col="0" row="2"/>

    </GridLayout>
    <Button text="Sign up for Groceries" class="link" tap="register" verticalAlignment="bottom" col="0" row="0"/>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
```

by assigning same row number `row="0"` they will overlap to each other taking full height because of `rows="*"`.
now we will set `verticalAllignment` of respective row to set it's position on top,bottom or center.

Comment: Wow.. Its working. Can u guide me for NativeScript ??

Comment: guide you for what?

Comment: Can I get ur mail ID? I will ask some doubts, So that will be helpful for me. I am very new to HTML, CSS, XML, SCRIPTS. So, I am facing lot of problems in learning. So, if any queries, I can ask u directly.

Comment: ping me on linkedin at: www.linkedin.com/in/bhavin-jalodara

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577389/nativescript-listview-items-are-reusing-when-scrolling Kindly help me on this.